# Python passing variables between functions (boolean)

Tags: python, return, boolean

EDIT:
Ok, after some input from everyone here, I managed to make it work! I simplified it a lot to get rid of the long chains. Here's what I have:

```
def main():
    var = (raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
    a = get_number(var)
    if a != False:
        switch = by_three(int(a))
        if switch == True:
            return
        else:
            print "Try again!"
            main()
    else:
        main()


def get_number(parameter):
    if parameter.isdigit():
        return parameter
    else:
        print "No, I said an INTEGER. \"%s\" is not an integer." % parameter
        return False


def by_three(placeholder):
    if placeholder % 3 == 0:
        print "%d is divisible by 3. Isn't that terrific." % placeholder
        return True
    else:
        print '%d is not divisible by 3. Boo hoo.' % placeholder
        return False

print "Let's find an integer divisible by 3."
main()
```

Is there any reason I shouldn't go back to main() in my else statements? Is there another way to get the program to go back to the beginning?

———
I tried to build a simple command-line program for finding numbers divisible by 3. The idea is to keep asking for a number until the user picks one that's divisible by three. Here's my code:

```
def main():
    print "Let's find an integer divisible by 3."
    var = (raw_input("Enter an integer: "))
    switch = False
    get_number(var, switch)
    while switch != True:
        print "Try again!"
        main()

def get_number(parameter, nd):
    if parameter.isdigit():
        by_three(int(parameter), nd)
        return parameter, nd
    else:
        print "No, I said an INTEGER. \"%s\" is not an integer." % parameter
        return parameter, False


def by_three(placeholder, tf):
    if placeholder % 3 == 0:
        print "%d is divisible by 3. Isn't that terrific." % placeholder
        return placeholder, True
    else:
        print '%d is not divisible by 3. Boo hoo.' % placeholder
        return placeholder, False

main()
```

OK, so here's what I thought was happening: variable `switch` gets passed to `nd`, which gets passed to `tf`. If the other variable (which goes var>parameter>placeholder) IS divisible by three, there's a return of True for `tf`—which should mean that the variable is now changed when I test it with "while."

That must not be what's happening—can someone explain how I'm misunderstanding things so badly? Passing variables around functions (and returning them!) is pretty confusing to me.

Comment: Why do you think your code isn't working? I ran it with positive and negative test cases and it passed: Let's find an integer divisible by 3.
Enter an integer: 3
3 is divisible by 3. Isn't that terrific.
Try again!
Let's find an integer divisible by 3.
Enter an integer: 6
6 is divisible by 3. Isn't that terrific.
Try again!
Let's find an integer divisible by 3.
Enter an integer: 5
5 is not divisible by 3. Boo hoo.
Try again!
Let's find an integer divisible by 3.
Enter an integer:

Comment: @ShawnMehan Oh, yeah, I guess I wasn't clear about that. I wanted the program to keep asking for more numbers until there's one that's divisible by three. It's supposed to end once there's a number divisible by three.

Answer (score 5):

### Let us focus on this portion of your code:

```
...
switch = False
get_number(var, switch)
while switch != True:
   ...
```

### What you are doing in this code snippet:

You have a variable, `switch`, which is `False` in the beginning. You send that to a function, and you check if it is `True` or not afterwards.

### Why this does *not* makes sense?

Let's consider the following program:

```
def changeVariable(a)
   a = a * 2

a = 5
changeVariable(a)
print(a)
```

This program still prints `5`, because **basically stated**: What you do in a function, stays in the function.

So, in your case, calling `get_number(var, switch)` and checking the value of `switch` does not make sense, because it will be `False` **all the time**.

### Solution:

You can use `return` statements. Then, you will have the **output** of your function.

Example:

```
def changeVariable(a)
   a = a * 2
   return a

a = 5
result = changeVariable(a)
print(a)
print(result)
```

The above code will print `5` and then `10`.

Comment: Or you can specify `global a` in the function.

Comment: @Alexander: He doesn't appear to have that bad habit; let's keep it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I'm having trouble, though, because I'm dealing with variables I don't know the values of—they need input from the user. And I can't just say "placeholder = var" because one of them is outside the function. Ugh, there's just so much I don't know.

Answer (score 4):

When you define a function, the `value` that you return via `return value` is given to the function itself, *not* the arguments passed to the function.

For example,

```
def f(i,j):
  i=1
  j=2
  return i,j

i=3
j=4
i,j=f(i,j)
```

will give i=1 and j=2, but

```
f(i,j)
```

will leave i and j unmodified (i=3 and j=4) because the scope of the variables inside the function is local.

Comment: Okay, thanks! That's helpful. I modified the code to be more direct: switch = by_three(int(var))

I'm still having trouble getting the value of by_three(var) to resolve to True or False. I thought I could do that from inside the If statement, but I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

so `tf` isn't used anywhere. There is a value passed into the `by_three` method, but then it isn't used in the method and hence isn't available to be returned. Right now, switch -> nd -> tf. And `by_three` accepts `tf` but doesn't put it to work.

`by_three` is correctly setting `True` or `False` for your problem, and passing it back up the chain to `nd` -> `switch` where it is being used in the conditional `while` correctly.